# How can i get the URI of my ECR image using aws CLI

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli, amazon-ecr

aws ecr list-images  --repository-name <repo_name>
I am using this but is it not returning me the URI of image instead returning the Image Tag and Digest which is not my need.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jDSBQ.png)

Expecting the Image URI

Comment: read the comments here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74437857/how-to-get-uri-of-image-in-ecr-using-aws-cli#comment131407213_74437857

Comment: You wont get it in a single command, you will need 2 commands to create the correct image uri. use the  aws ecr describe-repositories --repository-name <repo-name> and extract repositoryUri and then do the list-images to get the tag.

Answer (score 2):

This command will help you to get all tags with image uri

```bash
aws ecr describe-images --repository-name maven --region us-east-2 --query 'imageDetails[*].imageTags[0]' --output json | jq --arg v `aws ecr describe-repositories --repository-name maven --region us-east-2 --query 'repositories[0].repositoryUri' --output text` '.[] | ($v + ":" + .)'
```

- `aws ecr describe-images --repository-name maven --region us-east-2 --query 'imageDetails[*].imageTags[0]' --output json` get all tags of repository
- `aws ecr describe-repositories --repository-name maven --region us-east-2 --query 'repositories[0].repositoryUri'` get repository uri
- `jq --arg v "$REPO_URI" '.[] | ($v + ":" + .)'` concat `$IMAGE_URI:$TAG`

Result looks like

```
"XXXXXXXXXXXX.dkr.ecr.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/maven:3.3.9-jdk-8"
"XXXXXXXXXXXX.dkr.ecr.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/maven:3.3.3-nexus-jdk-8"
"XXXXXXXXXXXX.dkr.ecr.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/maven:1.1-jdk-7"
"XXXXXXXXXXXX.dkr.ecr.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/maven:3.3.3-jdk-8"
"XXXXXXXXXXXX.dkr.ecr.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/maven:3.6.3-openjdk-11-docker"
"XXXXXXXXXXXX.dkr.ecr.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/maven:3.3.9-jdk-8-alpine"
"XXXXXXXXXXXX.dkr.ecr.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/maven:3.6.3-openjdk-11"
```

Comment: @Kamil please verify it, if works for you then mark as accepted answer.